# Telerik's RadSpell's StartSpellCheck error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am using the telerik's `RadSpell` control and am trying to fire it on the client side using the example shown here:

[Telerik Example of RadSpell](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/spell/spell_launching_upon_client-side_events.html)

I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'StartSpellCheck'`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try .startSpellCheck() (lowercase s) instead of .StartSpellCheck(). The RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX API methods and properties should always start with a lowercase letter. I noticed that the documentation is for the ASP.NET (classic) and not the ASP.NET AJAX (current) version of RadSpell. The new documentation is available at http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/spell-how-to-launch.html